# Build Windows CE apps in Rhostudio

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows-ce, rhomobile

I installed the RhoMobileSuite 5.2.2. I've a regular account in rhomobile.com.

When I try to run apps with run configuration ( windows mobile / windows CE ) it doesn't work and I get this error:

```
PWD: C:\Users\Administrator\workspace\store
CMD: rake run:wm
rake aborted!
Exception: Could not build licensed features

Tasks: TOP => run:wm => config:wm => config:common
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
-$TIME$- message [ First timestamp ] time is { 2015-09-05T10:52:55Z } milliseconds from start (0)
Connecting to rhomobile.com
Starting rhodes build system using ruby version: 1.9.3
-$TIME$- message [ config:common ] time is { 2015-09-05T10:53:02Z } milliseconds from start (6820)
Connecting to rhomobile.com
 **** NOTE: You use sdk parameter in build.yml ****************************************************************
   To use latest Rhodes gem, run migrate-rhodes-app in application folder or comment sdk in build.yml.
 **************************************************************************************************************
 **** ERROR: Could not build licensed features. ***************************************************************
   You have free subscription on rhomobile.com. RhoElements features are available only for paid accounts.
   The following features are only available in RhoElements v2 and above:
   - Barcode extension
   - Indicators extension
   - HardwareKeys extension
   - CardReader extension
   - Signature Capture
   - Windows Mobile/Windows CE platform support
   - Symbol device capabilities
   - Symbol WebKit Browser
   For more information go to rhomobile website
   In order to upgrade your account please log in to https://rms.rhomobile.com
   Select "change plan" menu item in your profile settings.
 **************************************************************************************************************
```

I've Windows 7 ultimate edition & Visual studio 2013 ultimate edition

I can run apps with rhostudio on iphone, android and win 32 rhosimulator

any help ?
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, to build Windows CE/Windows Mobile applications you need Visual Studio 2008, that's the latest Visual Studio version that support those Operative Systems.

I've done a quick test and it works for me using RMS v5.2.2 and Visual Studio 2008 (plus the WM6.5.3 SDK and the Symbol MC3000 PSDK for Windows CE support, [you can find the detailed setup on RMS documentation](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.2.2/guide/nativesdksetup#setup-for-windows-mobile)).

**If you're moving a project from a previous RMS version to the latest available, always remember to do a `rake clean:<your target platform>` as a first step.**

**Edit:** Forgot to mention the very important thing that, Windows Mobile/Windows CE support, requires a paid license. You can get more information on [RhoMobile website](http://rhomobile.com/pricing/) and looking at the API list where, [everything linked to Windows Mobile/Windows CE is marked as a paid feature](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.2.2/guide/apisummary).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it always doesn't work : I've uninstalled The VS 2013 and I've installed VS 2008 but it always doesn't work, I think that the documentation is old , could you help me more sir and i ask if i can have your email ??

Comment: You just need to check that you've all the [requirements installed](http://docs.rhomobile.com/en/5.2.2/guide/nativesdksetup#setup-for-windows-mobile) and that you have at least a Silver RhoMobile license. Because [Windows Mobile/Windows CE support requires a paid license](http://rhomobile.com/pricing/).

Comment: Thank you sir that was very helpful